# Do my setttings for a friend's event calendar affect just me, or are my friend's preferences affected as well?

Tags: google-calendar

When I change my calendar notifications for a calendar/events set up by a friend, it just affects MY notifications, correct?

My friend's calendar/event notification settings for themselves aren't affected are they?

Answer (score 2):

I believe any changes you make will not be reflected in your friends shared calendar, unless you have write permissions to that calendar, then all bets are off.